# System.Windows.Interactivity DLL Count

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I am using the Expression Blend SDK and have references to `System.Windows.Interactivity` so that I can take advantage of `Behaviour`s and `EventTrigger`s etc. Great.

I noticed recently that using this library copies `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`, but also lots of other files/folders to my bin folder.

> **Directories:** ar, de, fr, it, et al. (clearly culture/localisation files).
>
> **Files:** es-ES, es-GT, es-HN, et al.

I do not plan on localising my application in some of these languages/cultures.

**What is the bare minimum I need for the use of `System.Windows.Interactivity` in my code and why are these files/folders included in the bin directory by the build process?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that you only need to keep the ones that specify your particular country and language. However, is it *really* worth removing them... they shouldn't be much bigger than a few Megabytes.

The one way that you can test which ones you *can* remove is by removing the ones that do not relate to the culture settings in your application and then trying to run the application... if it works, then it's ok to remove them. Mind you, when you run the application, it will rebuild and replace the removed dlls.

UPDATE >>>

If you use `ClickOnce` to distribute your application, you *might* be able to remove these `dll`s from the published version if you open up the startup project properties page. Go to the `Publish` tab, then click the `Application Files` button. In the `Application Files` dialog that opens, you can select which files are included with the published application.

Comment: Thanks. It is annoying to have to clutter the installation directory with files I don't need. The user may never see these files but if they are redundant I am reluctant to include them. I wondered if there was a way to stop the auto-inclusion of these files...